# Draggable UI Values with Meteor Handling Reactivity (see Bret Victor's Tangle)

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

Bret Victor created a cool library called Tangle for reactive documents a few years ago.  You can see an example here:
http://worrydream.com/Tangle/TangleTemplate.html

I love the simple way you can drag values.  I am trying to build a simple mortgage calculator where you could drag interest rate, years, etc.  My hope was to do something similar in my UI and have Meteor handle the reactivity.

My initial thought is to leverage the UI elements of TangleKit (http://worrydream.com/Tangle/TangleKit/)  perhaps via creating a package out of the JS files?  I don't know the best way or if there are other ways.  So looking for advice or ideas to get to the end result with Meteor.

The full doc is here:
http://worrydream.com/Tangle/download.html

The Git repo is here:
https://github.com/worrydream/Tangle

Thanks for any guidance.  This is all new to me.

------- UPDATED 4/14 9PM PST

Still no luck, but close I think.  See below.

COFFEE:

```
if Meteor.isClient
    console.log "Client is alive."
    Session.set("cookies", 4)

    Template.reactive.cookies = () ->
        Session.get("cookies")

    Template.reactive.calories = () ->
        Session.get("cookies") * 50

    Template.reactive.events
        'click .EditableValue': () ->
            newCookies = Math.round(accounting.formatNumber((Random.fraction() * 10),1))
            Session.set("cookies", newCookies)

    Template.example.rendered = () ->
        element = @find("#example") # Searches only within this template
        tangle = new Tangle(element,
          initialize: ->
            @cookies = 4
            @caloriesPerCookie = 50

          update: ->
            @calories = @cookies * @caloriesPerCookie

            # Insert your Meteor updating code here, for example:
            Session.set("cookiesQuantity", @cookies)
            )
    Template.example.cookies2 = () ->
        Session.get("cookiesQuantity")

if Meteor.isServer
    console.log "Server is alive."
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Reactive Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> reactive}}
    {{> example}}
</body>

<template name="reactive">
    <h5>This is a simple reactive document.</h5>
    <h4 id="example">When you eat <span class="EditableValue"> {{cookies}} cookies</span>, you will consume <span class="ReactiveValue"> {{calories}} calories</span>.</h4>
</template>

<template name="example">
  <p>This is a simple reactive document.</p>
  <p id="example">When you eat <span data-var="cookies"
   class="TKAdjustableNumber" data-min="2" data-max="100"> cookies</span>, you 
   will consume <span data-var="calories"></span> calories.</p>
   {{cookies2}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can just use Tangle as-is, and within the tangle’s `update` function, add a line or two to tell Meteor about the change.

Taking the example you linked to, convert the page into a Meteor template:

```
<template name="example">
  <p>This is a simple reactive document.</p>
  <p id="example">When you eat <span data-var="cookies"
   class="TKAdjustableNumber" data-min="2" data-max="100"> cookies</span>, you 
   will consume <span data-var="calories"></span> calories.</p>
</template>
```

Then you initialize the Tangle inside that template’s `rendered` callback:

```
Template.example.rendered = function () {
  var element = this.find("#example"); // Searches only within this template

  var tangle = new Tangle(element, {
    initialize: function () {
      this.cookies = 4; // Or Session.get("cookiesQuantity"), for example
      this.caloriesPerCookie = 50;
    },
    update: function () {
      this.calories = this.cookies * this.caloriesPerCookie;
      // Insert your Meteor updating code here, for example:
      Session.set("cookiesQuantity", this.cookies);
    }
  });
```

And make sure you put Tangle's files inside a `client/lib/tangle` folder so that they get sent to the client.

Comment: Hi @Geoffrey I tried the above and added the tangle files to client/lib/tangle.  I can make a reactive version NOT using tangle and using click events, but it misses the draggability I wanted.  I also tried your code, but could not get it to work either.  I think the library is loading as I don't get an error on "Tangle", but the values don't show.

Comment: Actually I am now getting "Class Not Defined" and "Tangle Not Defined" in the console.  I have my files in client/lib, but something else must be off.

Comment: Maybe I should try to make a Tangle package?

Comment: For client-side libraries like Tangle, the only benefits to creating a package are that your files get organized within a folder (which you already have with `client/lib/tangle`) and that you can use `package.js` to specify file load order. If you’re relying on TangleKit which looks like it needs to be loaded after Tangle, you could create a package to specify such, or just use Meteor’s load order: `client/lib/tangle/lib/tangle` for Tangle.js (loads first) and `client/lib/tangle/tanglekit` for TangleKit (loads after) etc.

Comment: As for the code you posted after I posted my answer, you’re creating a conflict between Meteor and Tangle as to updating the values. I  shouldn’t have suggested using `{{cookies}}`; really the DOM within Tangle’s domain should be managed only by Tangle to avoid trouble (see my actual code, not my comment after). If the initial values aren’t always the same, they need to be set within Tangle’s `initialize` function, and not by Meteor template helpers. Get rid of all your helpers and then see if it works.